# How to make Yii CListView to display WYSIWYG formatted text?

Tags: yii

On the admin side, I've used a WYSIWYG editor for all textareas.

When we format that with bold for example, the following string is stored in the database:

```
<b>hello bold</b>
```

However, when I try to see that text in bold, I, instead see something like this:

```
"<b>hello bold</b>"
```

The goal (so I suppose) would be to remove those double quotes, in order to allow us to see the proper formatted text.

Here's the widget call:

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.BsListView',array(
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'itemView'=>'_view',
));
```

Here's the view he is calling:

```
<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('description')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo $data->description; ?><!-- Removed the encode from this line-->
    <br />
```

If I remove the `CHtml::encode`, this works, but, if I have like 500 textareas, should I go to each view and remove this `CHtml::encode` :s

Any clue?

Comment: The usage of encode() is to Encode special characters into HTML entities http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#encode-detail

Comment: You should probably remove encode when you print it. thats the issue you have so far as i can see.

Comment: Indeed it is. The problem is that, I should remove those lines for each and every textarea with wysiwyg editor in it... o.O far away from practical. :)

Comment: truly, around how many text areas do u have with wysiwyg editor and whats the wysiwyg editor you use ? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this with PHP "html_entity_decode" function

take a look here : http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/22237-clistview-raw-html/

```
<?php
$orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now";

$b = html_entity_decode($a);

echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now
?>
```

Ref: http://www.php.net/html_entity_decode

**Update**

You should remove chtml::encode when you print html tags contain data. thats the issue here.

The usage of encode() is to Encode special characters into HTML entities http://yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#encode-detail

Comment: thanks a lot. The thing is, where should I place that? On the CListView _view.php file? But I wish this behaviour to work for no matter what text field... does this makes sense?

Comment: also it would be easy if you can post the contains of CListView _view.php

Comment: I've updated my question. (just to make sure your solution still applies).

Comment: html_entity_decode() works on a string. dataProvider (passed as a CListView parameter, is an object). So I don't see how this works. The user on the forum has stated that this works, but didn't demonstrate how. Unfortunately. :)

Comment: could we perhaps extend the gii that is responsable for this _view generation and, for each text from a textarea field, remove the encode? :) That would be nice. :) If that's a lot of trouble, perhaps, can you update your answer with the Chtml::encode removal, so that I can accept it? Thanks.

Comment: I'm considering editing the Gii template of the _view files, so that, each time the database column is of type "text", don't encode. CDbColumnSchema object, may help... :D